# How to force content to be stretch in a 2x2 VideoWall (4 monitors) in QT WIDGET?

Tags: qt, widget

My OS is Ubuntu and I have a 2x2 VideoWall (4 monitors inside each other). I want to show my content (Imagine an Image) in Full Screen mode on this VideoWall. 
I have written the code with QT Widget.
How should I do it?
My problem is that the content is just shown in one of monitors and 3 of them are empty.

Comment: My guess was trying to solve this with `xconfig`. A collaborator recommended to have a look at [`xrandr`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr). You should try to convince your window manager that "fullscreen" spans over all monitors. Otherwise, do not use fullscreen in your Qt app. but stretch the window (manually or by [`QWidget::move()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#move-1)/[`QWidget::resize()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resize)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve this issue you can follow one of the following ways:

1. Imagine you can use some plugins like `Compiz`. In this way you can pack all the monitors into just one 4K monitor So you can use this code for a full screen widget:

   `widget.move(0,0);
   widget.resize(3840,2160);`
2. Imagine you do not want or you can not use such things. In this way you see all the monitors separately. Imagine monitors all placed like this:

   `1 2`

   `3 4`

Now if you open your Widget into monitor number 4, you have to stretch it into monitor 1 using `move` and `resize` and then using `show` (not `showFullscreen`) functions.

```
widget.move(-1920,-1080);
widget.resize(3840,2160);
widget.show();
```

Please pay attention that your widget object will be open in "display :0" and position of this is depends on your VGA card and monitors connectivity and your displays arrangement in "Display settings".